# Error Getting Var from Html form Meteor javascript

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, set, var

I'm trying to set a var from a html field. When I run meteor, it doesn't compile with any errors but if the submit button is clicked, the console says:

> Exception while invoking method 'submitme' TypeError: Cannot call method 'preventDefault' of undefined

I really can't figure this out...

So my html part is:

```
<template name="status">
  <form id="status">
       <input id="status" type="text" name="status"/>
       <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
     </form>

</template>
```

The javascript part for the event:

```
   submitme: function(event){


           event.preventDefault();

           var statusvar = document.getElementById("status").value;




                 alert("Submitted!");
                 Meteor.users.update({
                   _id: this.userId
                 }, {

                  $set:
                      {

                        'status': statusvar
                      }
                   });





       },
```

And finally

```
Template.status.events({'submit' : function(event) {
    Meteor.call('submitme');
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh
}
```

EDIT:
Fixed!

The helper below posted:

```
Template.status.events({
    'submit' : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh    
        var statusvar = document.getElementById("status").value;
        alert("Submitted!");
        Meteor.call('submitme', statusvar);
    }
});
```

This did not work.
I Replaced it with:

```
Template.status.events({

    'submit' : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh



        var statusvar = event.target.status.value;


        alert("Submitted!");
        Meteor.call('submitme', statusvar);
    }
});
```

It now works..! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues going on here. Meteor.call() should be making calls to server side code only; you can't attempt to access `document` from your `submitme` function, nor do you need an event.preventDefault() within `submitme` (and you're not passing anything in either, so there's no way to have access to `event`). Revamp your code like this:

```
//THIS MUST BE ON THE SERVER SIDE
submitme: function(statusvar) {
    Meteor.users.update({
        _id: this.userId
    }, {
        $set: {
            'status': statusvar
        }
    });
},

//CLIENT SIDE
Template.status.events({
    'submit' : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent page refresh    
        var statusvar = document.getElementById("status").value;
        alert("Submitted!");
        Meteor.call('submitme', statusvar);
    }
});
```

Your event function is going to extract the value from your HTML and then pass that variable to the server side Meteor method called `submitme`.

Comment: Thankyou.. Now the error does not appear on console but the status var becomes  null.  "status": null

Comment: Use the javascript console in your browser to validate that the `document.getElementById()` works properly, and add a `console.log()` on te server side to verify that the value is being passed properly.

Comment: Logging statusvar like this:   console.log(statusvar) returns undefined in console...